# How to create new directory every time on code deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a scenario where I want to create a new directory every time I push the code. The pipeline will run and it updates my existing directory pulling my all latest changes.
I want to keep the previous directory as it is and clone the complete directory every time with new name when pushed with the help of CodeDeploy.
My appspec.yml is as follows

```
 # Definition file for AWS CodeDeploy

version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/sample-app/
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/sample-app
    owner: www-data
    group: www-data
    type:
      - file
      - directory
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: codedeploy-prepare.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: codedeploy-setup-app.sh
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a blue/green style of deployment?

Comment: No, I have checked In-Place deployment. Is this possible in blue/green deployments?

Comment: If you're trying to achieve zero downtime deployments, you must use blue/green deployments. You can't deploy in a `/folder/<unique_name>` and then use that as active repository after everything is completed.

Comment: @GiamPy, thanks. Can you refer me some tutorial as well for Blue/Green Deployments?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/use-aws-codedeploy-to-implement-blue-green-deployments-for-aws-fargate-and-amazon-ecs/